# Error while import the NavigationDrawer sample for lollipop?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat, android-styles, eclipse-adt

[image]I just import the Navigation Drawer for Lollipop in eclipse. And I am facing the issue and unable to resolve for the same.
Here, I attached the picture.

Let me know, if you have faced such problems suggest me some ways to resolve this.
I am using Eclipse.[image]

Comment: Are you using the appcompat library?

Comment: yes, I m using the appcompat library I added the refrence for the same

Comment: [My reaction](http://i.giphy.com/26tPgtVcHZfZYbnUc.gif) when I see people using Eclipse for Android development.